# Excel Column Sorting

Tags: excel, sorting, match, vlookup

Im using Excel 2010... This problem has been plaguing me for hours and would save me a lot of time, I have really tried searching for the answer but dont know what I am looking for without explaining in detail.

Basically I have 5 columns of data. Column A contains a list of selected names, Column B contains a list of all names and Columns C to E contain data relating to all names:

```
A     B      C  D         E
steve adam   54 london    car
doug  andrew 25 essex     walk
adam  bert   31 newcastle walk
omar  barry  47 london    car
      chuck  23 herts     cycle
      (columns continue)
```

I need to be able to sort the data so that the names in column A are in order and the other data in columns B to E match what is in column A with any non matches at the bottom of each list. So the result would look like:

```
A     B      C  D         E
adam  adam   54 london    car
doug  doug   37 norfolk   walk
omar  omar   31 dudley    jog
steve steve  74 london    cycle
      andrew 25 essex     walk
      (columns continue)
```

In real terms I have a list of thousands of names and need to match hundreds of names to them. If any one can help with this it would save me hours of work. I have tried searching and have watched many youtube vids on vlookup but nothing seems to be specific to what im after.

Thanks in advance

George

Comment: Are columns C, D and E sorted according to B? That what it looks like from your example.

Comment: yes and they need to remain intact if thats possible.. thanks :)

Comment: Are there names in A that don't exist in B?

Comment: there shouldnt be but there my be the odd typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel might not be the best tool for the job but try this:

1. Order column A by itself
2. In cell F1, use this formula: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1, A$1:A$4,1,FALSE), CHAR(142))`. Replace the "4" in `A$4` with the number of your last row of data (in both columns A and B).
3. Copy that down column F to the last row of data. You will see a `Ž` in rows where there isn't a match between A and B.
4. Select the data in columns B to F (leave A out) and sort using columns F as the first level and B as the second level (a single sort operation).
5. The data in A and B should align with the extra rows in B at the end.
6. If it doesn't align it means you have values in A that are not in B. Select the values in F, copy and paste special (values only) over the values in A. Delete all the `Ž`s from the end.
7. Delete column F

Comment: Hey acfrancis, thanks for your help. Im just getting a bit stuck on step 4 when you say sort by columns F and B do you mean 2 seperate sorts one after the other or sort by F with the b column sorted as a second level?

Comment: The latter. I updated the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: This has worked great.. the only thing is i didnt realise that there is handful of names that are in A that dont appear in B at all and the final sort relies on this not happening. I can change it manually but do u know of a simple way to account for this... dont worry if involves starting from scratch as this has been immensely helpful. Thanks again. George

Comment: I didn't mean my previous comment to be cryptic. I added a step before deleting column F.